# S.O.S. Visual Studio can't run go file, go: no such tool "asm"

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, assembly

I've been learning Go in Visual Studio Code and wasn't having any problems until I tried to create a mod file for the first time this morning. Now, whenever I try to run my code or reinstall Go tools, I get stopped by this error:
go: no such tool "asm"

I would appreciate detailed help (remember I'm a novice) on how to resolve this. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio Code, GO, and the GO extension in Visual Studio Code to no avail.

I've seen one other thread about a problem like this but it didn't give any understandable/detailed answers.

In case it helps here is the output from "go tool" and "go env".

Running "go tool" in my terminal gives:

```
addr2line
buildid
cgo
compile
cover
dist
doc
fix
go_bootstrap
link
nm
objdump
pack
pprof
test2json
trace
vet
```

Running "go env" gives:

```
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\cbh2132\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\cbh2132\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\cbh2132\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\cbh2132\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.18.2
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GOAMD64=v1
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=NUL
set GOWORK=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\cbh2132\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build1320767531=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Comment: Historically, Anti Virus programs caused this kind of errors (i.e. asm.exe was blocked or failed to get installed) often for Windows users. Check if you are experiencing the same issue. If so, configure the system to exclude it and reinstall Go.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! That does not sound plausible for two reasons. First, I do not have any formal anti-virus software downloaded on this computer and Visual Studio Code is allowed by the default Windows firewall. Second, all Go files were working just fine this morning and I have not updated any other software or added any anti-virus programs between when they were working and when the error started to occur. .

Comment: I was saying it because the `asm.exe` is from Go distribution (does have nothing to do with VSCode or Go extension) and often blocked by anti-virus program or window's default firewall software. If that's not the reason, I don't know but the Go installation on your program doesn't look complete. `go tool` should report `asm` if the installation is done correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem! So, even when I uninstalled Golang...I still had a file called "go" with all the package tools (e.g. asm.exe, etc) that was in my documents folder. I had to delete that file after uninstalling go and then reinstall go as well as the go tools in Visual Studio Code. Now it seems to be working again! This is such a relief.